# JFreeChart - Axis label positioning

Tags: java, jfreechart

I want the label of one of my axis to be two words, each aligned to the beginning and end of said axis - I've been doing this by inserting spaces in the Axis label, but it's a crappy solution.

Is there a way to align label text for a JFreeChart chart?

Thanks for any replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override [`drawLabel`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/Axis.html#drawLabel%28java.lang.String,%20java.awt.Graphics2D,%20java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D,%20java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D,%20org.jfree.ui.RectangleEdge,%20org.jfree.chart.axis.AxisState%29) to achieve any desired effect. Invoke [`getFontMetrics()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#getFontMetrics%28%29) on the parameter `g2` to position the text precisely. The JCommon class [`TextUtilities`](http://www.jfree.org/jcommon/api/org/jfree/text/TextUtilities.html), used extensively in JFreeChart, may offer more convenience.